# Function in SQL Server needs to have selectable parameters in Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, user-defined-functions

In SQL Server, I have a view which is constructed using a table-valued function. The function requires two dates. I would like to use the view in Power BI. How can I select the two dates in Power BI? Is this possible at all?

Otherwise, I have to define the view in SQL Server every time, and then update the query, which isn't very dynamic. I can add the SQL if need be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters This may help, to drive it from DAX, to the Power Query and then to the function. If you can, construct a table or view and use direct query mode, so it will generate the SQL query for you with the relevant start and end predicates

Comment: The short answer is you can't. This smells of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but posting the view definition (simplified!) would help illuminate your issue.

Comment: yes, I had problems trying the advanced editor method. I will try and go back a step. To see if I can solve the problem in a different way.